# почему вызов функции plus неоднозначный

Tags: c++

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
#define WORD unsigned short
void plus(int len, WORD * a, WORD * b, WORD * c);
int main(){
    WORD M[11],N[11],P[11];
    plus(11,M,N,P);
}
/* Функция вычисляет сумму чисел a и b, результат записывает в c.
 len - длина числа в словах.*/
void plus(int len, WORD * a, WORD * b, WORD * c)
{
 int i,h=0;
 long d;

 for(i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
  //d1=a[i];
  d=(long)a[i]+b[i]+h;
  c[i]=(WORD)d&0xffff;
  h=(d&0x10000l) ? 1 : 0;
 }
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста, почему вызов функции plus is ambigous?

ведь std::plus принимает 2 аргумента, а здесь определено и передается 4

компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
test-ambigous-minus.cpp:7:6: error: reference to 'plus' is ambiguous
        plus(11,M,N,P);
        ^
test-ambigous-minus.cpp:4:10: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'plus'
    void plus(int len, WORD * a, WORD * b, WORD * c);
         ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h:167:12: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'std::plus'
    struct plus : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, _Tp>
           ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Приведите полное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Потому что `std::plus` это не функция, а структура.

Соотвественно получилось

```
namespace std { template<class T> struct plus; }
using namespace std;
void plus(int len, WORD * a, WORD * b, WORD * c);
```

Поэтому и неоднозначность.

Вывод - не надо использовать `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 4):

Согласно стандарту C++ (7.3.4 Using directive)

6 If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in two different namespaces, and the declarations do not declare the same entity and do not declare functions, the use of the name is ill-formed. [ Note: In particular, **the name of a** variable, **function** or enumerator **does not hide the name of a class** or enumeration **declared in a different namespace**. For example,

```
namespace A {
class X { };
extern "C" int g();
extern "C++" int h();
}
namespace B {
void X(int);
extern "C" int g();
extern "C++" int h(int);
}
using namespace A;
using namespace B;
void f() {
X(1); // error: name X found in two namespaces
g(); // okay: name g refers to the same entity
h(); // okay: overload resolution selects A::h
}
```

> —end note ]

Как вы можете видеть из примера, взятого из стандарта, вызов `X(1)` является ошибкой.

```
X(1); // error: name X found in two namespaces
```

Если структура и функция с одним и тем же именем были бы определены в одном и том же пространстве имен, то функция скрывала бы имя структуры.

Например, если вы уберете директиву

```
using namespace std;
```

и в глобальном пространстве имен объявите также структуру с именем `plus`, как, например,

```
struct plus 
{
    plus(int len, WORD * a, WORD * b, WORD * c);
};

void plus(int len, WORD * a, WORD * b, WORD * c);
```

то ваш код успешно скомпилируется, и будет вызвана функция, даже не смотря на то, конструктор структуры имеет те же самые объявления параметров.

Если бы в стандартном пространстве имен `std` была бы определена функция, а не класс, то тогда бы в соответствии с правилами перегрузки функций была бы вызвана та функция, чьи параметры лучше подходят для заданных аргументов.

Вот пример, демонстрирующий сказанное

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N1
{
    void f( int ) { std::cout << "void N1::f( int )" << std::endl; }
}

using namespace N1;

void f( long ) { std::cout << "void ::f( long )" << std::endl; }


int main()
{
    f( 10 );
    f( 10l );
}
```

На консоль будет выведено:

```
void N1::f( int )
void ::f( long )
```

Однако если в пространстве имен N! вместо функции вы напишите объявление класса

```
namespace N1
{
    struct f { f( int ) { std::cout << "void N1::f( int )" << std::endl; } };
}
```

то получите исходное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: По поводу сокрытия имени структуры одноименной функцией добавлю, что структуру всё равно можно использовать, указав явно `struct` перед именем типа.